# prevent user from picking a date greater than today in sitecore forms

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am looking for a solution to restrict user from picking a date greater than today in Sitecore forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using OOTB validation on the Date Field like below.

Once you select a date in the Sitecore Form you can choose the validator like this.

[image]

So if you choose the `Past Date Validator` you will see the validation message like **The date must be in the past.**

And if none of the validator works for you then you need to create a custom validator and add it to your date field.

You can refer to this Sitecore article to create your custom validator

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-validator-based-on-the-existing-regular-expression-validation.html

Hope this helps.